How does tailscale serve up localhost to other devices?
I'm under the impression that with a docker compose like
services:
  exl2:
    image: exl2
    ports:
      - "5001:5000" # EXUI
      - "5002:8000" # JL
   ...

and no auth, I'm making myself vulnerable to other devices on the same network being able to access the service through these ports, or even if my router does port-forwarding without my knowledge.
My idea is to only open them to localhost, like ports: "127.0.0.5001:5000", and use tailscale serve to serve to my public net. Or even just bind to my tailscale IP? TSIP:5001:5000.
Initially I thought this was not working: without serving them I was still able to access them from other machines through TSIP:5001.
But then i checked using regular device id and it seems setting localhost will block them from accessing. Great!
But this begged the question how was tailscale able to  serve up localhost to other devices to access through the tailscale IP? Since  localhost is by definition only accessible on host?
Another strange thing, when I try to serve a dev server:
npx astro dev

 astro  v4.4.15 ready in 922 ms

┃ Local    http://localhost:4321/
┃ Network  use --host to expose

I am unable to access it on any address except localhost:4321/,
not even 127.0.0.1:4321. What gives? I thought localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1?
I'd like to learn more about this and don't expect answers handed to me, but don't know where to start.
